# How to gsub text randomly

Tags: r

I am trying to create some text. I have a data frame as follows (with many more rows of text in it)

```
out<-data.frame(c("The road it long. It has many a winding path","The rain clouds are coming","My aunt has blue hair. It is like Marj Simpson's hair","The oesophagus is long. It is like a toothpaste tube"))
```

I want to replace the 'It .' with 'and' but I want to do so randomly so that an example output would be:

```
The road it long and has many a winding path
The rain clouds are coming
My aunt has blue hair. It is like Marj Simpson's hair
The oesophagus is long and is like a toothpaste tube
```

how to I introduce the idea of random replacement into `gsub` or `str_replace`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Note that you are doing more than replacing `It` with `and`, you're also doing some replacement of punctuation (maybe).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am working on creating text reports for a project which are comprised of separate sentences. I want to introduce variation between the reports so random addition of conjunctions is one of many ways...The question has been updated to reflect getting rid of full stop as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get a `sample` of the possible value to replace and then do the replacement

```
v1 <- sample(c("and", "It"), nrow(out), replace = TRUE)
gsub("\\.\\s*(?=[a-z])", " ", str_replace_all(out[,1], "(?i)It", v1), perl = TRUE)
#[1] "The road and long and has many a winding path"
#[2] "The rain clouds are coming"                         
#[3] "My aunt has blue hair. It is like Marj Simpson's hair" 
#[4] "The oesophagus is long and is like a toothpaste tube"
```

Comment: OK that's clever thanks @akrun. So in other words you create a list of random 'It' and 'and' and then find and replace the whole dataframe so that replacing with itself creates no replacement giving the impression of random replacement.

Comment: @SebastianZeki  Thanks, yes, you can do the `sample` and with `str_replace` it will go through each individual elements of the replacement list and do this corresponding elements of the column